# Strong (trivial) cofibration in Lurie's HTT

Tags: category-theory, homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory, model-categories

in Lurie's book HTT in annexe A, proof of Proposition A.2.8.2 page 824, he mentions that a map is a "strong (trivial) cofibration" but I didn't succeed to find the definition of this notion that seems to come from nowhere. Do you have some insight ?

Thanks

Comment: Take it as a definition. Have you met *model categories*? http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/model+category

Comment: The word "strong" does not appear in the version I have. Can you quote the relevant part in full?

Comment: The latest version of HTT on Lurie's home page does not have the word “strong” in it.

Comment: yes thanks, I have loaded the last version and the word "strong" has disappeared, so now it's understandable.

Answer (score 1):

There is no word "strong" in Proposition A.2.8.2 in Lurie's HTT, at least in the version I have.